# In volleyball, is spiking off the blockers head considered a touch?

Tags: rules, volleyball

So, I know a block is considered a contact made close to and above the net. That being said, I was playing and my teammate spiked the ball through and touching a blockers arms (above the net) and bounced it off his head which was below the net. The ball stayed in play and they contacted the ball the standard 3 hits after that. My question being, does that make 4 hits with the contact off the head being considered the first contact? Or is the blocker's arguement that "it's all part of the block" correct and the head contact made below the net didn't count towards their 3 hits?

Answer (score 2):

> I know a block is considered a contact made close to and above the net.

You are incorrect. Quoting from [Rule 14.1.1](http://www.fivb.org/en/refereeing-rules/documents/FIVB-Volleyball_Rules_2017-2020-EN-v06.pdf)<sup>1</sup>:

> Blocking is the action of players close to the net to intercept the ball
> coming from the opponent by reaching higher than the top of the net,
> **regardless of the height of the ball contact**.

The blocker's arms were reaching higher than the top of the net, so this was a block contact and does not count as one of the three hits.

<sup>1. The "2017-2020" rules are still current in 2022; the four yearly update due in 2020 was delayed due to the COVID pandemic.</sup>